# Need to change WorkFlow to incorporate IF statement...not working!

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I have this workflow that I am using, working great.  Now I have a need to change the WF so that if the "Request Status" changes to "Access Denied", then email "xxxx" and stop workflow.  Here is an example of what I am trying to accomplish:

[image: Working flow]